# Time differences between 2 timestamps

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to find the `ride_length/duration` between `started_at` and `ended_at` in `HH:MM:SS`.

```
   SELECT
        ride_id,
        started_at, --timestamp
        ended_at, --timestamp
        ended_at - started_at AS ride_length
    FROM `case-study-1-bike-share-335613.bike_share.202102`
    ORDER BY ride_length DESC
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

1. Am I calculating it the right way? I know there's a `timestamp_diff` function in SQL Big Query but it limited to only one type of measurement such as hours, minutes **OR** seconds. I want it in `HH:MM:SS`.
2. How do I remove `0-0 0` from the `ride_length` column? Why doesn't SQL Big Query convert the exceeding hours into day, or exceeding day into weeks?
3. Since `ride_length` is a measurement of time, I try `SAFE_CAST((ended_at - started_at) AS time)` but got an error instead:

   Invalid cast from INTERVAL to TIME.

Should I just leave the column as it is? I can't have it convert to string because this table will imported to Tableau for visualization purposes. Thus it has to be some sort of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the difference in seconds and convert for the format you need:

```sql
WITH table_a AS
  (SELECT TIMESTAMP "2022-01-03 16:50:49 UTC" start_at, TIMESTAMP "2022-01-04 18:59:44 UTC" AS end_at)

SELECT start_at,
       end_at,
       regexp_replace(cast(time(diff) AS string), 
       r'^\d\d', 
       cast(extract(HOUR FROM time(diff)) + 24 * unix_date(date(diff)) AS string)) AS total_trip
FROM
  (SELECT start_at,
          end_at,
          timestamp_seconds(DATETIME_DIFF(end_at, start_at, SECOND)) AS diff
   FROM table_a)
```

[image]